# How do I use Chef Data bags to setup a mysql server

Tags: mysql, chef

Ok I'm getting started with Chef using the [opscode](http://opscode.com/) server.

I'm using the community cookbooks, and I've got basics working (I created a users/myname.json data bag and added the user::sysadmins recipe to my node, and that works fine, the myname user is created).

I added the mysql::server receipe to the node , which installs the server fine, however, where I am stuck is configuring the servers passwords using data bags.

I created a apps/dbmaster.json data bag, with the following contents

```
{
  "id":"dbmaster",
  "mysql_root_password": {
    "_default": "strawberry"
  },
   "mysql_repl_password": {
    "_default": "apple"
  }
}
```

but the mysql users are set up with the default passwords. I think I'm confused on how data bags are related to nodes ?  Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `mysql::server` recipe does not use data bags to set up the passwords by default. It uses node attributes, which get randomly generated in that recipe, unless they are present from another source such as a role.

- http://wiki.opscode.com/display/chef/Attributes
- https://github.com/opscode/cookbooks/blob/master/mysql/README.md

The `database::master` recipe in Opscode's database cookbook will manage the attributes based on values in a data bag for an application. This cookbook is intended to be used with the `application` cookbook also by Opscode, for managing application deployment and configuration integration through data bags.

- https://github.com/opscode/cookbooks/blob/master/application/README.md
- https://github.com/opscode/cookbooks/blob/master/database/README.md